# mysql making two categories unique to each other

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cs50

I have a row called user_id and symbol. I want to make it so each user_id can only have a certain symbol once.

This is the line I wrote to do this

```
ALTER TABLE  `portfolio` ADD UNIQUE (
`user_id` ,
`symbol`
);
```

However this makes it so I also can't have a user_id more then once. So if I add a column with a user_id = 21 and a symbol = AAA , I cant add another column with a user_id = 21 and a symbol = BBB.

ny ideas

Comment: Your understanding of the constraint is incorrect.  It does what you want it to do.

Comment: Sorry Gordan I didn't understand what you said. The constraint are incorrect/

Answer (score 2):

The following constraint does exactly what you want:  it makes sure that each user/symbol combination only appears once:

```
ALTER TABLE portfolio ADD UNIQUE (user_id, symbol);
```

A good practice when adding constraints is to give them meaningful names:

```
ALTER TABLE portfolio
    ADD CONSTRAINT unq_portfolio_userid_symbol
        UNIQUE(user_id, symbol);
```

That way, when the constraint is violated, you know *which* constraint is violated.  If you cannot add the user with another symbol, then perhaps `user_id` (or `symbol`) is declared as the primary key on the table or unique itself or as part of another unique column.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Menan 
 In this case you can use composite primary key

```
ALTER TABLE portfolio add 
constraint pkc_portfolio primary key (id, code);
```

Your combination of id and code will not be repeated